# ES6 Filtering objects by unique attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I've an array of errors, each error has a non-unique `param` attribute.

I'd like to filter the array based on whether the `param` has been seen before.

Something like this:

```
const filteredErrors = [];
let params = [];

for(let x = 0; x < errors.length; x++) {
    if(!params.includes(errors[x].param)) {
        params.push(errors[x].param);
        filteredErrors.push(errors[x]);
    }
}
```

But I've no idea how to do this in ES6.

I can get the unique params `const filteredParams = Array.from(new Set(errors.map(error => error.param)));`
but not the objects themselves.

Pretty sure this is just a weakness in my understanding of higher order functions, but I just can't grasp it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could destrucure `param`, check against `params` and add the value to params and return `true` for getting the object as filtering result.

As result you get an array of first found errors of the same type.

```
const
    params = [],
    filteredErrors = errors.filter(({ param }) =>
        !params.includes(param) && params.push(param));
```

Answer (score 1):

i'd probably do it like this with a `reduce` and no need for outside parameters:

```
const filteredErrors = Object.values(
  errors.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (!acc[val.param]) {
      acc[val.param] = val;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}))
```

basically convert it into an object keyed by the param with the object as values, only setting the key if it hasn't been set before, then back into an array of the values.

generalized like so

```
function uniqueBy(array, prop) {
  return Object.values(
    array.reduce((acc, val) => {
      if (!acc[val[prop]]) {
        acc[val[prop]] = val;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {}))
}
```

then just do:

```
const filteredErrors = uniqueBy(errors, 'param');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `Array.prototype.reduce`. You need to iterate through the objects in the array and keep the found `params` in a `Set` if it is not already there.

The `Set.prototype.has` will let you find that out. If it is not present in the `Set` you add it both in the `Set` instance and the final accumulated array, so that in the next iteration if the `param` is present in your `Set` you don't include that object:

```js
const errors = [{param: 1, val: "err1"}, {param: 2, val: "err2"},  {param: 3, val: "err3"},  {param: 2, val: "err4"}, {param: 1, val: "err5"}];

const { filteredParams } = errors.reduce((acc, e) => {
  !acc.foundParams.has(e.param) && (acc.foundParams.add(e.param) && 
                                    acc.filteredParams.push(e));
  return acc;
}, {foundParams: new Set(), filteredParams: []});
console.log(filteredParams);
```

Comment: Nice! So you're using params.add(e.param) and acc.push(e) in place of conditions, knowing that they'll only run if the first condition (!params.has) is satisfied?

Comment: @NickW Yes the `Set.prototype.has` returns a `boolean` and if that is `false` only then the next statements would be evaluated as `&&` is a short-circuit *and* operator. I did it that way to not have an `if` block and make the snippet short, but I guess having an `if` makes it more readable. Also the `Set.prototype.add` will return the `Set` instance and that would be *truthy* in JavaScript terms and so the next `Array.prototype.push` would always be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array you can make use of an object to keep a map of existing values and make  use of filter function

```
let params = {};

const filteredErrors = errors.filter(error => {
   if(params[error.param]) return false;
   params[error.param] = true;
   return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your param has a flag identifier if this param has been seen before then you can simply do this.

```
const filteredErrors = errors.filter(({ param }) => param.seen === true);
```

OR

```
const filteredErrors = errors.filter((error) => error.param.seen);
```

errors should be an array of objects.

where param is one of the fields of the element of array errors and seen is one of the fields of param object.